# Change Version in Package.appxmanifest in Xamarin UWP

Tags: xamarin, versioning, xamarin.uwp

I want to change the value for `Identity Version` in below code

```
    <Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
         xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
         xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" >
<Identity Name="Sample.Product " Publisher="CN=1234" Version="1.0.0.0" />
<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="456" PhonePublisherId="0" />
</Package>
```

I tried changing using following XmlPoke code.

```
    <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Package.appxmanifest" Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='n' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011' Name='N' /&gt;" Query="/n:Package/n:Identity/@Version" Value="$(Version)" />
```

the line doesn't change the version.

Whats going wrong in above code?

Comment: The version of the app being built. This is typically incremented each time the app is has been modified and packaged. To ensure that the `Version` is incremented correctly, use the dialog provided when you invoke **Store -> Create App Packages...** to make updates.

Answer (score 2):

Identity, which you're looking for, is in the default namespace of Package, so in your XmlPoke you'll need to use that namespace. To do that, change the URI of your XmlPoke to be `http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10`, like so:

```
    <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Package.appxmanifest" Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='n' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' /&gt;" Query="/n:Package/n:Identity/@Version" Value="$(Version)" />
```